# How to create PreferenceActivity xml in Android?

Tags: android, xml, listview

How to Xml Below Image?

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/98/62574826.png

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As shown in figure I am sure that this is PreferenceActivity.

So please read about it in [Android Developer Site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html).

Also If you need some fine examples with Custom Preference Screen.
Please visit this links.

1.[Android Preferences](http://androidpartaker.wordpress.com/2010/07/11/android-preferences/)

2.[SeekBar Preferences](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/seekbar_preference.aspx)

3.[Custom SeekBar Preference Without Dialog](http://androidboss.com/android-preferences/) [Dead Link]

4.[MultiChoice Preference Screen](http://blog.350nice.com/wp/archives/240)

Answer (score 2):

I think that is a PreferenceActivity. [See this link to know more about it](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html).

**Edit:**

Some Tutorials:

- http://android-journey.blogspot.com/2010/01/for-almost-any-application-we-need-to.html
- http://jetpad.org/2011/01/creating-a-preference-activity-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

Hey david you can do it by creating a Custom ListView

Here is the link for this...
http://sujitdroid.blogspot.com/

Or if it is a Setting screen then follow this link

http://jetpad.org/2011/01/creating-a-preference-activity-in-android/